# Meteor method return inside mongo insert callback

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor method in which I want to return a value to the client. When I put the return statement inside the outer scope of the method, the value is returned. But when I put the return inside the callback of a mongo insert operation, the value is never returned. To clarify I want the value to be returned after the insert operation has succeeded.

Thank you in advance.

In meteor.methods

```
create_hackathon: function(){
   Hackathons.insert(hackathon, function(err, result) {
              if(err) {
                  console.error("error creating hackathon");
                  return false;
              } 
             return result; // doesnt work.
   });
   return "test"; // works.
}
```

Comment: This question gets asked all the time. Think about what your internal return returns from (the callback function of the insert). See duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I might be able to make it run synchronously by using var x = ... but I wasn't sure.